# fromJust doesn't convert maybe int value

Tags: haskell

From my putCursorTo function i'm calling the findWord function, which returns a Maybe Int value. This is processed by fromJust, to store the index value. Why does it throw a signature error?

I have tried to add an Int input signature for the putCursorTo but that wasn't the error

```
putCursorTo :: String -> [String] -> [String]
putCursorTo word t = do
    index <- [fromJust (findWord word t)]
    let (x,y) = splitAt index t
    init x ++ [last x ++ "^"] ++ y 

findWord :: [String] -> Maybe Int
findWord t = find t 0
    where
        find [] _ = Nothing
        find (x:xs) c
            | "^" `isInfixOf` x = Just c
            | otherwise = find xs (c+1)
```

The error that i'm getting is on the line `index <- [fromJust (findWord word t)]` telling me that the variable fromJust is not in scope.

I'd like to get it working so the index value stores value of the findWord function, that is converted with fromJust to an integer

Comment: Have you imported `Data.Maybe`? You also don't really need to use `do` notation here.

Comment: @Lee I forgot to include that yes, thank you ! However now i'm getting an error saying i couldn't match [string] with maybe int. Any ideas why that might be?

Comment: If you read the full error message it tells you the problem: "The function ‘findWord’ is applied to two arguments, but its type ‘[String] -> Maybe Int’ has only one".

Comment: `x <- [y]` looks as a complex way to write `let x = y`. I can't understand why you are using `do` and monads there, it feels unnecessary complex. Also, you should avoid `fromJust` since it's a partial function. Use `case findWord t of Just i -> ... ; Nothing -> ...` and handle the "not found" case properly instead of crashing the program.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of using `Maybe` is to force users of `findWord` to consider the possibility that `findWord` could fail. `fromJust` ignores that possibility. A better definition of `putCursorTo` would be

```
putCursorTo :: String -> [String] -> Maybe [String]
putCursorTo word t = do
    index <- findWord word t
    let (x,y) = splitAt index t
    return $ init x ++ [last x ++ "^"] ++ y
```

Here, we *try* to extract an `Int` from the result of `findWord`. If it succeeds, we can proceed as usual, except we lift the final result back into a `Maybe` value. If the extraction *doesn't* succeed, because `findWord` returned `Nothing`, then `putCursorTo` will return `Nothing` as well, by definition of the `Maybe` monad.

The alternative is to have some default index in mind should `findWord` fail. We can provide that using the `fromMaybe` function:

```
putCursorTo :: String -> [String] -> [String]
putCursorTo word t = let (x,y) = splitAt (fromMaybe 0 (findWord word t)) t
                     in init x ++ [last x ++ "^"] ++ y
```

Replace 0 with whatever index makes sense if `word` isn't found. Or, maybe if `findWord` fails, you just return the original list as-is:

```
putCursorTo :: String -> [String] -> [String]
putCursorTo word t = case findWord word t of
                       Nothing -> t
                       Just index -> let (x, y) = splitAt index t
                                     in init x ++ [last x ++ "^"] ++ y
```

---

All that said, there's a mismatch between the definition of `findWord` and how you call it. Perhaps the call should be `findWord t` instead of `findWord word t`.